# Npm dev server won't start after pulling from github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github

Hi I just cloned my project from my GitHub user and now `npm start` won't start the dev server...
it sends this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! airlines@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the airlines@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Maybe I have to install the dependencies from the package.json?
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The dependencies haven’t been installed yet. Run `npm install` to install the dependencies, then you can run `npm start`.